# MySQL SELECT WHERE... AND (based on parameter value)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

```
@Query(value =
            "SELECT * " +
                    "WHERE (type REGEXP ?1) " +
                    "AND status= ?2 " +
                    "AND date(createdAt)..." +
                    "ORDER BY id DESC " +
                    "LIMIT ?4",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<List<Item>> findLatest(String type, String status, String date, int limit);
```

I have this query where I'd like to filter by **createdAt**, only if the **date** value from the parameter is not null.

If `String date = null`, the query should not consider the `AND date(createdAt)...`

However if `String date = "today"` the query should include something like `AND date(createdAt) = CURRENT_DATE`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Simplified you can make

If you have more choice you need case when

The idea is when the condition is not met, we let the and part always be true
so that the where calsue is true if all the other conditions are met

```
SELECT * FROM
A
WHERE
    status= 72 
    AND IF( date = "today" , date(createdAt), current_date) = current_date
```

Answer (score 0):

The way we usually handle this is by adding a logical check to the `WHERE` clause which allows a null date.

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * " +
               // ...
               "WHERE (type REGEXP ?1) AND " +
               "      status = ?2      AND " +
               "      (DATE(createdAt) = ?3 OR ?3 IS NULL) " +
               "ORDER BY id DESC " +
        nativeQuery = true)
Optional<List<Item>> findLatest(String type, String status, String date);
```

Note that it is not possible to bind parameters to the `LIMIT` clause, therefore I have removed it.  Instead, you should use Spring's pagination API.